# How to stop an in-progress release with the Microsoft Release Management client?

Tags: release-management, ms-release-management

How do I stop/cancel a started and in-progress release deployment using the Microsoft Release Management client?

Answer (score 1):

If you are a member of the group assigned to the Deployment step, you will have the ability to stop/pause an in-progress release.

Answer (score 0):

You can click on the Stop button if you open the release that is in progress.